# Extract some value in click listener from outer class

Tags: java, android

I have a custom class which has a unique interface

```
public class CalculatorDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
  TextView mView;
  CalculatorListener delegate = null;
  public CalculatorDialog (Context context, CalculatorListener delegate) {
    this.context = context;
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }
  public interface CalculatorListener extends OnClickListener {
    @Override void onClick(View v);
  }
  @Override void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    mView = (TextView) findViewById(...);
    findViewbyId(...Button...).setOnClickListener(delegate);
  }
  public String getViewText() {
    mView.getText().toString();
  }
```

When creating new object of CalculatorDialog I want to implement my own action for clicking Button, but I want to get some String from a visible text view.
So in my MainActivity I try to do this:

```
CalculatorDialog dialogBox = new CalculatorDialog(context, new CalculatorDialog.CalculatorListener() {}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String test = getViewText();
    }
});
```

But as you and I have thought it can't be accessed from there.
Code here is not 1:1 with what I have in my project, but I think it represenets my needs. Also I have wrote it directly on StackOverflow, so it may contain some code bugs.
How can I access this function?

Comment: Why don't you just define your interface method to pass back the `String` you want, instead of relaying the `OnClickListener`?

Comment: Do you mean Jesses anwser?

Comment: Yeah, something like that, now that they've changed it. You probably don't really need the `View` parameter, though.

Comment: Correct, I don't need it

Answer (score 1):

You should change your CalculatorListener

```
 public class CalculatorDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
  TextView mView;
  CalculatorListener delegate = null;
  public CalculatorDialog (Context context, CalculatorListener delegate) {
    this.context = context;
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }
  public interface CalculatorListener{
    void onClick(View v, String text);
  }
  @Override void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    mView = (TextView) findViewById(...);
    findViewbyId(...Button...).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             delegate.onClick(view, getViewText());
        });
  }
  public String getViewText() {
    mView.getText().toString();
  }
```

and

```
CalculatorDialog dialogBox = new CalculatorDialog(context, new CalculatorDialog.CalculatorListener() {}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, String text) {
        String test = text;
    }
```

Comment: getViewText() is in CalculatorDialog, not MainActivity. Yet `double a = CalculatorDialog.this.getQuantity();` is saying that `CalculatorDialog is not an enclosing class`

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this is the only possibility.

Comment: Yeah, this looks much better. Will test it soon